# Recall a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a simple image slideshow using jQuery. I need the "next" button to execute exactly the same function I use on each image click above. Since I am noobie, I can't get the issue.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/etajuv/6/edit)

```
$('.show').each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.children('li').hide().eq(0).show();

      var activeli = $this.find('li');

      activeli.click(function() {
              var $this = $(this);
              var $next = $this.next();
              if ($next.length === 0) {
                      $next = $this.parent().children(':first');
              }
              $this.hide();
              $next.show();
      });

      // My issue is there
      $('.next').click(function() {
              activeli.click();
      });

});
```

Comment: First, you don't need the $() around "activeli" when you call the .click() on it (in both cases). Second, you add the .click event to all the li elements you find in your html page. And i suppose, you should have only one active element. To that end, you should probably add a special css-style to the active element to single it out of the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to filter what activeli will be clicked but:

```
$('.next').click(function() {activeli.filter(":visible").trigger("click");}
```

is the basics, note that you dont need to wrap activeli with jquery because you have it already when you find the li in the first place.

Comment: It partially solves the problem but as you can see [with many slideshows](http://jsbin.com/etajuv/8/edit) , `.next` buttons are not associated with the closest `ul.show`. `$this.children('.next')` is not working. How can I do that ?

Comment: I would have done it like this: http://jsbin.com/etajuv/9/edit you need to find something that connects both next and your sliders togheter, so I added a wrapper, and rewrote you script to look for the wrapper and its content instead.